# Cython output file becomes 5x larger

Tags: python, cython

I have recently upgraded from python3.6 to python3.8. When I use cython to build the same python code, the output file become 5x larger. I noticed the output file name also stripped the "m" and became "XX.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so". It was "XX.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so". Anyone has encountered this issue? thanks for the help.

Comment: The "m" is pretty uninteresting. It just means that Python is "built with pymalloc" (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/#proposal). I'd guess the file size is probably to do with debug symbols being included, but I don't know why that's changed, or how to test it.

Comment: The source code is exactly the same. I suspect it could be some other packages got upgraded as well. Need to find a way to analyze content of the .so file.

Comment: `strip --strip-debug <name-of-so-file>` will remove debug symbols (be aware it'll modify the file in place, so you may want to make a copy). That may help identify if they are the problem

Comment: hey David, you saved my day. It reduced both my .so files to around the same size and much smaller. So there must be a difference between python3.8 and 3.6.

Comment: Some updates. The .so file stripped debug symbols didn't work in production machine. It simply says "module not found". I've since used pyenv to downgrade the python in my dev environment.

Comment: I don't know. You need to ensure that the Python versions are the same, the 64 bitness is the same, the platform is the same. There's a verbose flag for Python that gives more info during module import - that might help.

Comment: The other question would be "does it work on the production machine if you don't strip the symbols?"

Comment: i think the unstripped version probably will not work as well due to the version difference. I'll test out the stripped .so (same python version as production) in next production deployment. It should work.